# getting the height of image loaded in Flash AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm testing code on my PC. Loading images from local folder and trying to get the height of an image loaded after a button click. The code is something like, in frame 1

```
jpgHolder.loadMovie("image"+i+".jpg");
```

the variable i is added by 1 after clicks

in frame 2 I want to trace the height of the image by

```
trace(jpgHolder._height);
```

after the first click I got 0 in te output. After the second click I got the height of the previous image loaded, and so forth. Why I'm getting the height of the previous image loaded and how can I solve this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `trace` is being called *before* the loading completes.

To `trace` the correct height, for the correct image, you need to check whether it's finished loading.

You can do it like in an `onEnterFrame` loop, but the best way to achieve this in AS2, is using the `MovieClipLoader` class and a listener object:

```
// create the loader
var loader : MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();

// create a listener object: an object that holds event callbacks
var listener : Object = {};

// assign the "onLoadInit" to the listener. this will be called when loading completes
listener.onLoadInit = function(mc :     MovieClip, status : Number) : Void {
    trace("height:" + mc._height);
};

// load the file into the container "jpgHolder"
loader.loadClip("image" + i + "test.jpg", jpgHolder);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved my question in a way close to your, but I give you the points.